# why does ranges::view_interface<T>::size require a move constructor

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts, std-ranges

I don't understand where the requirement for moving comes from. I can't find it in `forward_range` and `sized_sentinel`...
Basic example:

```
    #include <ranges>
    #include <string>
    #include <iostream>
    
    class vrange: public std::ranges::view_interface<vrange>
    {
        public:
            vrange(std::string &d): data(d){;};
    
            vrange(const vrange &&) = delete;
    
            auto begin() const noexcept { return data.begin(); };
            auto end() const noexcept { return data.end(); };
    
        private:
            std::string data;
    };
    
    int main(){
        std::string h("Hello world");
        vrange r(h);
    
        std::cout << r.size() << std::endl;
        for (const auto &i: r){
            std::cout << i;
            }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        
    
    }
```

removing the call to `r.size()`, or defaulting the vrange move constructor and assignment operator makes it compile fine.

compiler message:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/bits/ranges_util.h: In instantiation of ‘constexpr _Derived& std::ranges::view_interface<_Derived>::_M_derived() [with _Derived = vrange]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/bits/ranges_util.h:101:35:   required from ‘constexpr bool std::ranges::view_interface<_Derived>::empty() requires  forward_range<_Derived> [with _Derived = vrange]’
w.cpp:25:12:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/bits/ranges_util.h:70:23: error: static assertion failed
   70 |         static_assert(view<_Derived>);
      |                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/bits/ranges_util.h:70:23: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/ranges:37:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/concepts:136:13:   required for the satisfaction of ‘constructible_from<_Tp, _Tp>’ [with _Tp = vrange]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/concepts:150:13:   required for the satisfaction of ‘move_constructible<_Tp>’ [with _Tp = vrange]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/concepts:247:13:   required for the satisfaction of ‘movable<_Tp>’ [with _Tp = vrange]
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12/include/g++-v12/concepts:137:30: note: the expression ‘is_constructible_v<_Tp, _Args ...> [with _Tp = vrange; _Args = {vrange}]’ evaluated to ‘false’
  137 |       = destructible<_Tp> && is_constructible_v<_Tp, _Args...>;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `size` specifically.

`view_interface` is used to build a type that is a view. Well, [the `ranges::view` concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/view) *requires* that the type is at least moveable. And `view_interface` has a [very specific requirement on the type given as its template argument](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/view.interface#2):

> Before any member of the resulting specialization of `view_interface` other than special member functions is referenced, `D` shall be complete, and model both `derived_from<view_interface<D>>` and `view`.

Well, your type does not model `view` because it is not moveable. So you broke the rules, and you therefore get undefined behavior. Which can include compile errors happening if you call certain members but not others.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the language design does not allow CRTP types to require a diagnostic once the derived type is complete.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts: That would require that the language recognize that the CRTP is a thing. Which it doesn't.

Comment: So it could be argued that it is too lenient in regard to the `view` concept when using only `begin()` and `end()` ? UB being UB, i know it could have blown up my PC, but for argument's sake...

Comment: @serafean: What is "too lenient"? Nothing in `view_interface<D>` is able to apply the `view` concept to `D` because `D` is incomplete at that point. Only after `D` has been fully defined can you ask if it is a `view`; by then, it already has a `view_interface`.

Comment: lenient - not strict enough. What you're saying implies to me that when using only the iterator getters the view concept doesn't even get applied.